# Error 32: The process cannot access the file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to delete an image if it throws an IOError when trying to open it with PIL, but for some reason my try, except setup here doesn't work.

When I run this, it gives the error:
**WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:**

```
dir_src = 'D:\\images'
folderlist = os.listdir(dir_src)

for folder in folderlist:
    flag = False
    dir_src_fine = dir_src + '\\' + folder
    filelist = os.listdir(dir_src_fine)

    for x in filelist:
        flag = False
        name = dir_src_fine + "\\" + x

        try:
            im = Image.open(name).convert('RGB')
            im.close()

        except IOError:
            os.remove(name)
```

Comment: This example could be shortened quite a bit.

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the original file as soon as you are done with it. Right now you don't save a copy, so do the open/convert in two steps. Initialize `im` to `None` before you attempt to use it and also include close logic in the exception to make sure it has really been released.

```
dir_src = 'D:\\images'
folderlist = os.listdir(dir_src)

for folder in folderlist:
    flag = False
    dir_src_fine = dir_src + '\\' + folder
    filelist = os.listdir(dir_src_fine)

    for x in filelist:
        flag = False
        name = dir_src_fine + "\\" + x

        im = im2 = None
        try:
            im = Image.open(name)
            im2 = im.convert('RGB')
            im.close()

        except IOError:
            if im:
                im.close()
            os.remove(name)
        finally:
            if im:
                im.close()
            if im2:
                im2.close()
```

Comment: Hmm, I still get the same error: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: Perhaps there is something external holding it. In the shell, you could just try opening it.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks for the help!